# Arrow keys in OpenBSD's ksh, command line editing, Vi-mode

Tags: command-line, ksh, openbsd, arrow-keys

I'm using the default [`ksh` on OpenBSD 6.2](http://man.openbsd.org/ksh) (based on `pdksh`) with Vi command line editing mode enabled.

I'm trying to get the arrow keys to work properly as a complement to <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> (as I'm on a Dvorak keyboard).  As far as I can tell, they don't work at all. It does not matter whether I'm in "input" or "command" mode.

The current key bindings includes:

```
^[[A = up-history
^[[B = down-history
^[[C = forward-char
^[[D = backward-char
```

These are also the character sequenced produced by my arrow keys if I use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Arrow key</kbd>.

The arrow keys works as expected in Emacs command line editing mode, but as a long time Vi user, I feel somewhat crippled when using it.

My feeling is that the Escape that is sent by the arrow key is interpreted as if I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>... I get the equivalent behaviour by manually typing e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> as when I press <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> (places me in command mode and then in insert mode at the end of the line).

Question: Has anyone been able to get the arrow keys to work intuitively in Vi-mode in OpenBSD's `ksh`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a quick foray into [`/usr/src/bin/ksh`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/ksh/) on my OpenBSD system, seeing as I had the actual sources checked out anyway. I had a cursory glance at `c_ksh.c`, `emacs.c` and `vi.c` and it looks as if the Vi mode was retrofitted into `pdksh` from `nsh` at some point (around 1989/1990). The exact words used are

```
/*      $OpenBSD: vi.c,v 1.55 2018/01/16 22:52:32 jca Exp $     */

/*
 *      vi command editing
 *      written by John Rochester (initially for nsh)
 *      bludgeoned to fit pdksh by Larry Bouzane, Jeff Sparkes & Eric Gisin
 *
 */
```

The `bind`-able functions all live in `emacs.c`, as does the `x_bind()` function which gets called by the `bind` builtin, while `vi.c` seems to have its own implementation of some of them under different names that are not called from `x_bind()`.

Therefore I think I can conclude that the `bind` builtin is a no-op in Vi-mode in this particular shell.

UPDATE (2018-02-04): After reporting this to the `openbsd-misc` list, it was confirmed that `bind` does indeed not do anything in Vi command line editing mode. A patch will go in to modify the `ksh` manual on OpenBSD so that this is mentioned:

> `bind string=[editing-command] ...`
>
> In *Emacs editing mode*, the specified editing command is bound to
>                the given `string`.  Future input of the `string` will cause the
>                editing command to be immediately invoked.  **Bindings have no
>                effect in *Vi editing mode*.**